# Set the class attribute to Html.EditorFor in ASP.NET MVC Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

As you know we can set attributes to actionLink or textBox in razor views but how can we set attributes to `@Html.EditorFor`, I know the EditorFor is a dynamic element that can be set according to model type, but all shapes of that can get the attributes. So is there any way to set attribute to `@Html.EditorFor` something like this: `new {@class = "myclass"}` ?

Comment: There are no overloads for this, therefore you cannot do this. Why don't you just use the actual type you want (e.g. TextBox) and pass it to that

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The `EditorFor` helper renders the corresponding editor template. It could be the [default template](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-3-default-templates.html) or some custom template that you wrote. This template could contain any markup. It could contain many DOM elements. So now you understand that asking for applying a class to a template doesn't make any sense. To which element on this template you want this class to be applied? For example with the TextBoxFor helper you know that it will generate a single input field, so it makes sense to talk about applying a CSS class to it (that's exactly what the `htmlAttributes` argument allows you to do).

This being said there are different techniques. For example one that I like very much is to write a custom data annotations model metadata provider and custom editor templates as outlined in the [following blog post](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/kiran/archive/2009/11/29/Adding-html-attributes-support-for-Templates-_2D00_-ASP.Net-MVC-2.0-Beta_2D00_1.aspx).

Another possibility is to customize the default templates (as shown in the Brad Wilson's blog post) and apply different HTML attributes to the corresponding input field. Let's take an example with the string.cshtml editor template:

```
@model string
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, ViewData)
```

And now when you want to render this editor template for some string property on your view model:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.SomeStringProperty, new { @class = "myclass" })
```

Comment: I use this class for inputs with type=(text , file) and select(drop down).

Comment: @dotNetist, OK, so as outlined in my answer you have a couple of different ways to implement this.

Comment: thank you, but before I read the references you mentioned, I have a question about it: I don't want to set the attribute for all of the (for example) string types, I have a custome attribue(in my model) and I changed the codetemplate(T4) and I need the property with that specific custom attribute set the 'myclass' attribute in editorfor helper, so is that you think or not?

Comment: @dotNetist, with both approaches involved in my answer you do not globally set it for all string types. With the first approach you decorate your view model property that you want to get the CSS class applied with the HtmlProperties attribute and with the second approach you pass it as argument to the EditorFor helper which obviously applies only to that given property.

Answer (score 62):

Try this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Comment: HellBaby is right that this is the new syntax for MVC 5.

new { htmlAttributes = new { @style = "width:20px" } } as an example works for the style attribute as well.

Comment: This doesn't work for people who are stuck in MVC 4.

Comment: Works for Core 2.X

Answer (score 10):

Add custom attributes as

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @data_minlength = "3", @class = "form-control input-md", @placeholder = "Name", @required = "required", @id= "txtName"} })
```

Replace data- to @data_

It will generate correct html with data-

Comment: This works for MVC 5.1+, but not for earlier versions. FYI.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the original poster was correct

- each **`EditorFor()`**

  creates a main `HTML element` (though there may be others present), so it would be very helpful to be able to pass an *object* containing `HTML attributes` to apply to that main `HTML element`.
- I want to apply the **`HTML 5`**  *'autofocus'*  attribute to one *field* on every **form**,
- but I DO NOT want to have to write custom code.
- I hate the fact that I'm currently reduced to using, e.g., `@Html.TextBoxFor()` for that one *field* just so that I can apply specific *attributes* to the `input element`.
- The `EditorFor()` method does have a *parameter* they call `additionalViewData`, but I have no idea what you can do with that and searching on **MSDN** has not been of any help to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple code for adding class to `@Html.EditorFor()`

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Demo)

<style type="text/css">

#Demo
{
   color:#fff;
   width: 50%;
}

</style>
```

this code works fine for MVC3